# Firebase queries and compound indexes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following document structure in firebase:

```
{
 typeId: number,
 tripId: number,
 locationId: string,
 expenseId: number,
 createtAt: timestamp
}
```

I want to query this collection using different 'where' statement everytime. Sometimes user wants to filter by type id and sometimes by locationId or maybe include all of the filters.

But it seems like I would need to create a compound index of each possible permutation? For example: `typeId + expenseId, typeId + locationId, location + expenseId,` etc, otherwise it doesn't work.

What if I have 20 fields and I want to make it possible to search across all of these?

Could you please help me to construct a query and indexes for the following requirement: Possibility to query across all fields, query can contain one, two, three, all or no fields included in where clause and always has to be ordered descending order by createdAt.

Comment: You need to add all the indexes

Comment: In this case, firebase is useless! How come anyone is using it?

Comment: @WildGoat If you don't need an order, you can use any possible permutation without the need of creating an index.

Comment: thanks but I need a order by createdAt :(

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore automatically creates indexes for the individual fields of your documents. So it can already filter on each field without you have to manually add these indexes.

In many cases it is able to combine these indexes to allow queries on field combinations, by performing a so-called zig-zag-merge-join.

Custom additional indexes are  typically only needed once you add an ordering-clause to your query, in addition to filter clauses. If you have such a case, the Firestore client will log an error telling you exactly what index to create (with a link to the Firestore console that is prepopulated to created the index for you).

Comment: Thanks! Could you please help me to construct a query and indexes for the following requirement: Possibility to query across all fields, query can contain one, two, three, all or no fields included in where clause and always has to be ordered descending order by createdAt.